# When uploading memory stream with contents created by csvhelper using SSH.NET to SFTP server, the uploaded file is empty

Tags: c#, sftp, memorystream, csvhelper, ssh.net

I'm truing to send a CSV with csvhelper. But when I send it, it is always empty.

```
using (var sftProvider =new SFTProvider(Configuration))
using (var csvProvider=new CSVProvider(Configuration))
using (Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    var sftp = sftProvider.SFTPConnection("", "", "");
    var nameFile = "/ethias/"+DateTime.Now.ToString(DateFormatConstants.DATE_FORMAT) + ".csv";
    if (sftp.Exists(nameFile))
    {
        sftProvider.ReadFileSFTP(sftp, nameFile, fileStream);
    } 
    await csvProvider.WriteCsv(new List<EthiasResultDTO>() {ethiasResultDto},fileStream); 
    sftProvider.UploadFileSFTP(sftp,nameFile,fileStream);
}
```

The code for the csv:

```
public async Task WriteCsv<T>(List<T> csvInfo, Stream stream)
{
    using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";

        if ( stream.Length > 0)
        {
            csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        }
        csv.WriteRecords(csvInfo);
    }
}
```

i try serveral things but it always empty file that is create .

Comment: Into the same fileStream, you first apply ReadFileSFTP(), then WriteCsv() . I think what you do is to get a file from an FTP location, append some records to it, then to put it back. If this is the case, just set `fileStream.Position = 0;`before passing it to `UploadFileSFTP`

Comment: If the suggestion by @OguzOzgul does not help, we will need [mcve]. You haven't told us anything about the FTP/SFTP library. It's not even clear if you use FTP or SFTP.

Comment: i use sftp Renci.SshNet

Comment: i only have a generique class for sftp

Comment: i only do the recovery of the record if there a file but i have the problem also when i only create and ad a new file the record in the csv is empty

Comment: System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream. i have this error when i use using in my methode writecsv

Comment: I think you need something similar to the answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093150/using-csvhelper-to-output-stream-to-browser

Answer (score 0):

You have to seek the read pointer of the stream back to beginning after writing to it. This is covered for example in these questions:
[Upload data from memory to SFTP server using SSH.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45945512/850848)
[Upload from ByteArray/MemoryStream using SSH.NET - File gets created with size 0KB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35862714/850848)

---

For that you also have to make sure that the `StreamWriter` does not close the memory stream:
[Is there any way to close a StreamWriter without closing its BaseStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2666888/850848)

---

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, true))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    // Write
}

stream.Position = 0;
```